Ubuntu 24.04 apt update says Skipping acquire of configured file component sutton.newell
I don't know what to replace it with, I have found similar posts here, but none offers solution, regarding sutton.newell.
I need proper drivers...
root@acop:/# apt update
    Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
    Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                                                                                                                                
    Hit:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                        
    Hit:4 http://rs.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                                                                                                                             
    Hit:5 http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease                                                                                                                             
    Hit:6 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease                                                                                                                      
    Hit:7 https://repo.waydro.id jammy InRelease                                                                                                                      
    Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease                                              
    Hit:9 https://debrepo.freedownloadmanager.org jammy InRelease                           
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree... Done
    Reading state information... Done
    All packages are up to date.
    W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
    W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
    W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
    W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
    W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
    W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
    W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
    W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
    W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.newell/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.newell' (component misspelt in sources.list?)


What is this? sutton.newell Read the whole message the update does not know what it is either.
